Prevent SSIS from connecting to a data source in design time
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with the latest SSIS extension (1.3.2). In my dtsx package I have a connection manager which I don't want to be touched by VS in design time (I'm not manipulating or changing any tasks or components which deal with this connection manager).
I thought the property DelayValidation on the connection manager should help, but even after changing it to true I can see a Login attempt being logged in a SQL Server Profiler immediately after I open the package in VS.
The only workaround I've found is to activate "Work offline" but then every connection manager is offline (and the setting is per developer and doesn't seem to be persisted) which is not practicable for me.
Any suggestions are very appreciated.
*This connection manager is referencing a normal SQL Server database for a case if it matters.

What is the problem you are facing? Meaning, why don't you want SSIS to do what it does?

It's a production system outside of my control. Accessing it during nightly jobs is fine (as it was settled) but I don't want to get into discussions why I'm logging in at some arbitrary time points.

Then in that case, you should have your VS IDE configured to point connections to the DEV server(s), and have your packages use a configuration file for the connection strings. This way, you deploy to production and update the connection string config to point to production server(s), and your DEV environment (VS IDE) won't show connections to production.

There is no dev/test environment for this system which is reachable for me

If you don't have a dev server to point to, you're out of luck.

Why not spin up some local db with some tables or shudder a container that you can use as some sort of testing ground

You have identified the only option: "Work offline" but it as you state, that applies to all connections. There is no ability to selectively have one connection offline while the rest remain online.
DelayValidation does not prevent this and every edit to a component/transformation in a data flow is going to cause the Validate (name approximate) method to fire at which point SSIS has delayed validation as long as possible.

In the Visual Studio IDE, open your SSIS project. Then, point your connections to the DEV server(s) of your data sources. Then, change the SSIS package(s) to use configuration files. Your development environment no longer points to your production server(s).
When you deploy your packages to the production environment, change the SSIS package(s) configuration file(s) to now point to your production data sources.
